# do i need to edit connection string in my c# application when i install it in a client pc, if yes how can i do it?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have created a software in C#, using SQL Databases (SQL server).
and I'm planning to deploy it and use  SQL Server Compact instead of installing SQL server in the client PC .

and it seems that i need to replace the connection string in my code so it contain the name of the client PC . (I'm not sure 100% ).

so if i have to change it how can i do it , and is there is any way to generate the connection string and change it in my code automatically when i install my app or after i install it in other PC's .

thank you .

Comment: How are you deploying your application? It'll be easier for you to have a different configuration file with the connectionstring, then use that file when you deploy.

Comment: Will `localhost` work at the client machine name?

Answer (score 0):

Add the connection string to the App.Config and get the code to get the connection string from the App.Config. That way, when releasing to any environment, just change the value in the one place.

Answer (score 0):

You should code the connection string so that it can be dynamic, as opposed to making it hard-coded in the config.  Passing a connection string in code before your db call is trivial.